# he App Store Icon in the asset catalog in 'OMS.app' can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

All of my images are .jpg what am I missing here

[image]

I am also not seeing the remove alpha in the preview export

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may use an online converter to convert jpg to png. And yes, App icon can't contain an alpha channel. To remove that, you can do the following.

- Open you png icon in Preview
- Click `File` > `Export`
- Uncheck `Alpha`
- Save

You can strip the alpha channel by doing so, and then re-upload and make your icon.

[image]

Comment: Check out the update to the question. I am not seeing the remove alpha option. All of my images were png than I changed it png and still got the same error

Comment: @Darron, I see you are trying to export the image in jpg format. I believe you should first convert the image to png, then open the png in Preview, `Alpha` option will appear.